# it has invalid type error at map i am unable to resolve it

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
public class DynamicTableController {
    public List<SelectOption> SupportedObject { get; set; }
    public String SelectedObject { get; set; }
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    Set<String> ObjectKeys = gd.keySet();
    public List<SelectOption> fieldLabelAPI { get; set; }
    public List<String> selectedFields { get; set; }
    public List<SObject> ObjectList { get; set; }
    public DynamicTableController() {
        SupportedObject = new List<SelectOption>();
        SelectedObject = '';
        fieldLabelAPI = new List<SelectOption>();
        selectedFields = new List<String>();
        ObjectList = new List<SObject>();
        for (schema.SObjectType item : ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId.getDescribe().getReferenceTo()) {
            if (!item.getDescribe().customSetting) {
                SupportedObject.add(new SelectOption(item.getDescribe().getLocalName().toLowerCase(), item.getDescribe().getLabel()));
            }
        }
    }
    public void ObjectFields() {
        if (SelectedObject != '--none--') {
            schema.SObjectType SystemObjectType = gd.get(SelectedObject);
            schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = SystemObjectType.getDescribe();
            Map<String, Schema.SobjectResultField> M = r.fields.getMap();
            for (schema.SObjectField fieldAPI : M.values()) {
                fieldLabelAPI.add(new SelectOption(fieldAPI.getDescribe().getName(), fieldAPI.getDescribe().getLabel()));
            }
        }
    }
    public void ShowTable() {
        String myQuery = 'SelectId';
        for (String field : selectedFields) {
            if (field.toLowerCase() != 'id' && field.toLowerCase() != '--none--')
                myQuery += ',' + field + '';
        }
        myQuery += 'form' + SelectedObject + 'LIMIT 100';
        ObjectList = Database.query(myQuery);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a standard class called `Schema.SobjectResultField` but there is one called `Schema.SObjectField` (that you reference a couple of lines later) so one fix is:

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> M = r.fields.getMap();
```